# Pairwise correlation between raster layers in R

Tags: r, correlation, raster

I need accomplish a pairwise Pearson correlation between 19 raster layers for Africa Continent extracted from WordClim database. I want to checking what are variables layers more correlated/significant to my model. For this i tried use the  layerStats function from Raster package, but after execute my output not contain numerical values, all the rows and columns showed NAs values. 
Below is my script.

```
#Loading raster files from WorldClim database
rastFiles<- list.files(pattern="bil")
a<-stack(rastFiles)

# Adjusting for African Continent
newext<-c(-20, 55, -35, 45)
Africa<-crop(a,newext)
Africa

#Correlation
cor<-layerStats(Africa,'pearson')
```

Comment: If you're using r, please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to identify the programming language, i use R.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In r, simply use the code below, ensuring you have na.rm=T to deal with NAs across layers:

```
library(raster)    
jnk=layerStats(raster_stack, 'pearson', na.rm=T)
corr_matrix=jnk$'pearson correlation coefficient'
```

Comment: hello, have you any idea why my layerStats function might return "Error: Failure during raster IO"? Before stacking 2 rasters, i did have to change the extent of one to match the other. thanks

Comment: What does `jnk$'mean'` tell us? I can't find anything about this. Thanks